# how install sarge for a while

Tags: debian, bios

I want to upgrade BIOS. But the only way is to run an app designed for Debian 3.1 (Sarge). So the easiest solution is run sarge live CD, run app - and be happy. Unfortunately - the only ISOs are netinst and businesscard. And the bad news is, I can't install because this computer has no floppy and no CD - hp t5720 workstation. The only way is usb.

Any ideas?

Or how to run module compiled for 3.1 on other Debian (I have no sources of course)

**WORKAROUND**

I found the workaround - found that i can use MS-DOS flash bios, so I use http://rufus.akeo.ie/ to make freedos boot usb, and I finally flash it, but for academical reasons - the question is still valid - HOW TO RUN Debian 3.1 without cd and floppy

Comment: Debian Sarge was end-of-lifed in 2008 and has thus been insecure for 8 years now.

Comment: @ceejayoz Great, but what is value of your comment? I don't want to using, I want to run ONE app for one minute, flash bios, and forget about sarge again

Comment: SF has a policy of closing questions about unsupported software/hardware. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8504/unsupported-setup-is-it-a-valid-question

Comment: Not to mention that this thin client is over 10 years old and has been end of life for almost as long. Unless you're a computer museum, you probably should not be trying to use one.

Comment: @ceejayoz If it is only used to upgrade the BIOS, then it can be done offline, and eliminate that security problem.

Comment: @kasperd That's nice, but it doesn't make it any less off-topic.

Comment: I wonder what is with people, which has to use XEON for easy tasks. This thin client works perfectly on debian Jessie, and do the job with very low power consumption. For 5$ + USB drive. And all problems gone with new BIOS (1.02->1.12). And I don't want to support Debian Sarge - just INSTALL, RUN AND FORGET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Knoppix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoppix) is a Debian-based distro designed to be run directly from CD / DVD / USB flash drive. You can find Knoppix archive ISO images in http://iso.linuxquestions.org/knoppix/

Debian GNU/Linux 3.1 (Sarge) was released on 6th of June, 2005. The first Knoppix available image is 3.4, released 2004-05-17, so I guess you will find the right version there.